# Not able to pass additional props to {this.props.children}

Tags: reactjs, jsx, next.js

I am new to React and wanted to pass a certain parameter as props to {this.props.children} in my Layout Component (which is the parent one). I tried this using React.cloneElement but it returns an error that "React.cloneElement(...): The argument must be a React element, but you passed null." even though it works with just this.props.children.

I am also using next.js for routing, could it be that there is a different method to do this functionality with next?

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import { Container } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import Head from 'next/head';

class Layout extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { user : props.user}
    }

    
    render(){
        const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>
            React.cloneElement(child, { userName: this.state.user })
          );
        return(
            <Container>
                <Head>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css" />
                </Head>
                <Header  />
                {childrenWithProps}
        </Container>
    )
    }


}

export default Layout;
```

```js
React.cloneElement(...): The argument must be a React element, but you passed null.
Error: React.cloneElement(...): The argument must be a React element, but you passed null.
    at Object.cloneElement (http://localhost:3000/_next/1576310783506/main.js:4066:13)
    at Object.cloneElementWithValidation [as cloneElement] (http://localhost:3000/_next/1576310783506/main.js:5192:33)
    at http://localhost:3000/_next/1576310783506/page/accounts/uploadNew:179066:40
    at mapSingleChildIntoContext (http://localhost:3000/_next/1576310783506/main.js:4391:26)
    at traverseAllChildrenImpl (http://localhost:3000/_next/1576310783506/main.js:4253:5)
    at traverseAllChildrenImpl (http://localhost:3000/_next/1576310783506/main.js:4269:23)
    at traverseAllChildren (http://localhost:3000/_next/1576310783506/main.js:4334:10)
    at mapIntoWithKeyPrefixInternal (http://localhost:3000/_next/1576310783506/main.js:4416:3)
    at Object.mapChildren [as map] (http://localhost:3000/_next/1576310783506/main.js:4440:3)
    at Layout.render (http://localhost:3000/_next/1576310783506/page/accounts/uploadNew:179065:62)
```

Comment: Have you tried filtering the Children before passing to React.cloneElement?
`React.Children.filter(child => child !== null).map( ... )`

Comment: Yes I've tried it but it gives an error that "_react2.default.Children.filter is not a function"...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it eventually by using : this.props.children.slice(1) since the first element was undefined in the object array.